# Summarizing calories for a food diary

Tags: beginner, c, linked-list, statistics

I'm new to C and I've been working on some code for a project for school. This was the finished result and now that I'm done it, I came back and tried making it better. So I was wondering, how would I make this `printAvgCalPerGroup` simplified?

```
#include "diary.h"

void printTotalCal(Food * list)
{
     int total = 0;
     Food * temp = list;

     while (!isEmpty(temp))
     {
          total += (int)temp->calories;
          temp = temp->next; // change to the next list item
     }

     printf("%d\n", total);
     return;
}

void printAvgCalPerGroup(Food * list)
{
     double vegCount = 0.0;
     double meatCount = 0.0;
     double dairyCount = 0.0;
     double grainsCount = 0.0;
     double fatCount = 0.0;

     double vAmnt = 0.0;
     double mAmnt = 0.0;
     double dAmnt = 0.0;
     double gAmnt = 0.0;
     double fAmnt = 0.0;

     Food * temp = list;

     while (temp!= NULL)
     {
          if (temp->foodGroup[0] == 'v')
          {
               vAmnt+=1.0;
               vegCount+=temp->calories;
          }
          else if (temp->foodGroup[0] == 'm')
          {
               mAmnt+=1;
               meatCount+=temp->calories;
          }
          else if (temp->foodGroup[0] == 'd')
          {
               dAmnt+=1;
               dairyCount +=temp->calories;
          }
          else if (temp->foodGroup[0] == 'g')
          {
               gAmnt+=1;
               grainsCount+=temp->calories;
          }
          else if (temp->foodGroup[0] == 'f')
          {
               fAmnt+=1;
               fatCount+=temp->calories;
          }
          temp = temp->next;
     }
     printf("%.2f\n", calcAvg(vegCount,vAmnt));
     printf("%.2f\n", calcAvg(meatCount,mAmnt));
     printf("%.2f\n", calcAvg(dairyCount,dAmnt));
     printf("%.2f\n", calcAvg(grainsCount,gAmnt));
     printf("%.2f\n", calcAvg(fatCount,fAmnt));

}

double calcAvg(double x, double y)
{
     double ans = x/y;
     if (ans != ans) return 0.0;
     return ans;
}

void run(char * argv)
{
     Food * f = getDiary(argv);
     printTotalCal(f);
     printAvgCalPerGroup(f);
     printList(f);
     destroyList(f);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Reducing repetition

The big if statement in `printAvgCalPerGroup` is a bit repetitive (as you pointed out).  Imagine if you increased the number of food groups.  You would have to copy/paste 4 places for each food group you added.

First, I would suggest using arrays for the counts and amounts of each foodgroup.  Then you only have to convert the letter such as `'v'` into an array index.

Second, if the food groups could possibly change, I would suggest using an `enum` to keep track of them.  This is definitely optional, and you could use hardcoded numbers instead (e.g. `'v' -> 0, 'm' -> 1`, etc).

Third, a small change to make would be to track the amounts using ints instead of doubles, since the amounts always increase by 1 only.

Here is what your code would look like using arrays and enums:

```
typedef enum FoodGroup {
    VEG,
    MEAT,
    DAIRY,
    GRAINS,
    FAT,
    FOODGROUP_MAX
} FoodGroup;

void printAvgCalPerGroup(Food * list)
{
    double    count[FOODGROUP_MAX] = {0};
    int       amnt [FOODGROUP_MAX] = {0};
    FoodGroup group;

    Food * temp = list;

    while (temp!= NULL) {
        switch (temp->foodGroup[0]) {
            case 'v': group = VEG;           break;
            case 'm': group = MEAT;          break;
            case 'd': group = DAIRY;         break;
            case 'g': group = GRAINS;        break;
            case 'f': group = FAT;           break;
            default : group = FOODGROUP_MAX; break;
        }
        if (group < FOODGROUP_MAX) {
            amnt [group]++;
            count[group] += temp->calories;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    for(group=0; group<FOODGROUP_MAX; group++)
        printf("%.2f\n", calcAvg(count[group], amnt[group]));
}
```

If you don't need the enum, just replace `VEG` with `0`, `MEAT` with `1`, etc.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted thanks, I didn't know about the enum being 0,1,2 etc so that was informative

Comment: You could even avoid the `switch` by creating an array of `FoodGroup`s, initializing it one time, and do the lookup by using temp->foodGroup[0] as the array reference.

Answer (score 7):

Having many similarly used variables suggests using an array:

```
    double calories[FOOD_CATEGORIES];
    double amount[FOOD_CATEGORIES];
```

and some means of translating `foodGroup[0]` to an index. In fact, I recommend to translate them right at the reading phase. Then the code collapses to

```
    while (temp != 0) {
        calories[temp->food_index] += temp->calories;
        amount[temp->food_index] += 1;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < FOOD_CATEGORIES]; i++)
        printf("%.2f\n", calcAvg(calories[i], amount[i]));
    }
```

That said, `printAvgCalPerGroup` does too much: it computes *and* prints. These independent responsibilities shall be given to independent functions.

Comment: Why would you use multiple arrays when you have the option of making an array of `struct`s?

Comment: @Snowbody For clarity (a baby step at a time).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `Food` (which is not defined, you forgot to paste in `diary.h`) has a pointer to another `Food` object in the `next` member. This seems to be an attempt to implement a linked list (or a stack).

However, the bigger question is why do you use this method of storing multiple `Food` items? You aren't doing anything that benefits from having a linked list like adding things in the middle. What's the reason for not using a standard array or dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: It was an assignment and that's the way we were told to do it for the assignment

Comment: And the linked list files are in a separate c file, I just wanted to know how to make this code shorter

Answer (score -1):

How about using alternative `switch` when you have a lot of `if-else` conditions?

Use data type `int` for the `amount` variables instead of `double`.

It is very simplified already.